# How to manipulate string in GNUmakefile for loop

Tags: gnu-make

I am new to GNUmakefile and I am just not sure how to handle the strings in the for loop below. I can print out each file using the echo command below. My questions are:
1. How to assign the $$f to a variable?
2. How to print out the content of the new variable?

For example, I did assign the content of `$$f` to "abc" but `echo ${abc};` prints out blank.
Where did I miss? Thanks

```
DIR := MyDir
CFILES := $(wildcard $(DIR:=/*.c))

.PHONY: all

all:
      for f in $(CFILES); \
          echo $$f;   \          
          abc=$$f;    \
          echo ${abc};   \
      done
```

Comment: The immediate answer to your question is you need to escape the `$` when you reference `${abc}`; this should be written `$${abc}` then it will work as you expect.  Without the escape make will expand `${abc}` (which has no value as a make variable) before it even starts the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is missing a do?

Inside the tabbed block you have scripting.
So you are setting shell vars not make vars.
You must escape the $s in shell block so printing $$abc or $${abc} would work. You can use make var as you have done $(CFILES).

What do you expect/want in abc ?
Do you wish to manipulate a shell or make var?

```
     echo CFILES=$(CFILES)
     for f in $(CFILES); do\
        echo ff $$f;\
        abc=$$f; \
        echo $${abc};\
        bn=$$(basename $$f);\
        b=$${bn%%.*};\
        echo you want this b= stripped down file tag $$b basename of file $$bn bash style;\
     done
```

As ever there are more than one ways of doing things.
Make style maybe you could use pattern rules and automatic vars to do what you want?

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples

e.g.

```
%.o : %.c
     echo make var $< matches file.c
     echo make var $@ matches file.o
     echo make var $* matches stem file
     echo $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to manipuate the $f . The $f is something like /dir1/dir2/file1.c and I want to extract "file1" from $f . How do I do that?

Comment: Do you know bash dirname and basename? Use them. In bash $(basename foo/bar/fee.fie) is fee.fie. Use bash var subst to strip .fie e.g. ${fname%%.*}. Escape $s in makefile. I will put example up in make block in answer.

Comment: That is the bash way of doing things. Make has special vars for chunking apart dir file and ext. need to read make manual. Simple make rule definition examples will show how that works . .

Comment: Perfect, they are answered. tx

Comment: @user2167013 [GNU Make File Name Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions) `$(notdir $(basename $(f))` should do it.